# How do I export a MySQL db structure to an Excel file?

Tags: mysql, excel

Is there any tool to export a MySQL db structure to an Excel file?
For example:

```
1   ID  int(10)  not null  pri   0  index   comment
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: [PHPMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) (and most MySQL tools) come with similar functions build-in. This does not really cover your question though.

Comment: I don't think you could export "MySQL *db structure*". My guess is you could only export *tables*.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Of course, what i want is export table structure. Do you have any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 17):

Here is a much simpler way:

1. From phpMyAdmin, select your database, then select the Structure tab.
2. Scroll down to the bottom of the list of tables.
3. Click on Data Dictionary.
4. Select all, and then copy/paste into Excel.

This method produces a report listing all tables, plus all fields within each table including the field type, if NULL is allowed, default value, links, comments, and MIME.  It also lists all indexes including type, uniqueness, whether the index is packed, and index comments.

Comment: Its helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You could query [`information_schema.columns`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/columns-table.html) to obtain the required data:

```
SELECT * from information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'db_2_66028'
AND table_name = 'tbl';
```

- `table_schema` is the name of your db
- `table_name` the name of the table. If you omit this, you will query column information for all your tables.

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23f9b/1 for live demo. Here I used `SELECT *` for simplicity, but you will probably have to select only the require columns for your specific need.

---

In addition, MySQL is able to export query result as [CSV file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), a text format that Excel, like any other spreadsheet, might easily read. Something *like* that might do the trick:

```
SELECT * from information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'db_2_66028'
AND table_name = 'tbl'
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY ‘\\’
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want:

```
SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM table
```

Comment: It works, but how can i export with over 100 tables. If i do manually, it takes a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

You could export it to a comma seperated file (.csv) using a simple php script. That can be imported in Excel.

For example:

```
<?php
    $dbc = mysql_connect( $a, $b, $c );
    $q = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM table", $dbc );
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $q ) ) {
      echo "{$row[0]},{$row[1]},{$row[2]}\n";
    }
?>
```