# How to export from mysql database to database document table definition book

Tags: mysql, information-schema

My problem is that I am getting a mysql database with lots of tables. And the need to output the same document as the file I attach, Is there any tool that supports this?

Thanks so much.

[image: Database document spec]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I export a MySQL db structure to an Excel file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989067/how-do-i-export-a-mysql-db-structure-to-an-excel-file)

Answer (score 0):

The information you want is in the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html), or the output of [SHOW COLUMNS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html).

Comment: Thanks you. I know that, I remember in Eclipses has one plugin for export but i forgot name. :( I will write script and export using php.

Answer (score 0):

there is a tool to select the column from each table you want to extract on excel.
check [Microsoft tutorial](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Microsoft-Query-to-retrieve-external-data-42a2ea18-44d9-40b3-9c38-4c62f252da2e)

you should obtain this menu :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5a9I.png)

and you just drop the column you want